# Below query is giving error in creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This sql query is giving me a error while executing it I could not understand where the problem is please help me here

```
CREATE TABLE failed: CREATE TABLE projects_of_1-2453852243(proj_id VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(256),
 mentor VARCHAR(128),
 team_leader VARCHAR(128),
 abstract TEXT, description MEDIUMBLOB,
 domain VARCHAR(80),
 department VARCHAR(80),
 reference VARCHAR(128),
 submission_yr int,
 proj_field VARCHAR(2))
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-2453852243(proj_id VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title
>   VARCHAR(256), mento' at line 1

Comment: If you will be building identical tables for each 'project', don't.  That is _usually_ a bad schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put backticks around your table name `projects_of_1-2453852243` as `-` is not directly allowed in identifiers. Also, `PRIMARY KEY` is already `NOT NULL`. There is no need to specify it with primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE `projects_of_1-2453852243`(
 proj_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(256),
 mentor VARCHAR(128),
 team_leader VARCHAR(128),
 abstract TEXT, description MEDIUMBLOB,
 domain VARCHAR(80),
 department VARCHAR(80),
 reference VARCHAR(128),
 submission_yr int,
 proj_field VARCHAR(2))
```

or use an underscore instead:

```
CREATE TABLE projects_of_1_2453852243 (
 proj_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(256),
 mentor VARCHAR(128),
 team_leader VARCHAR(128),
 abstract TEXT, description MEDIUMBLOB,
 domain VARCHAR(80),
 department VARCHAR(80),
 reference VARCHAR(128),
 submission_yr int,
 proj_field VARCHAR(2))
```